# fligner.test on R for multiple columns

Tags: r, anova

I've been working on this for most of today and cannot find the answer anywhere online.

I have a set of data with two factor variables and 30 dependent variables.  I would like to use the fligner test to determine whether the assumption of equal variance is met for EACH dependent variable, based on the interaction between my two factor variables.

I can do this for one variable at a time and get the p-value:

```
fligner=fligner.test(variable~interaction(factor1,factor2),data=mydata)
fligner$p.value`
```

But I can't do it for all the variables at the same time.  I've tried lapply (which is what I used to get all my shapiro.test data).  This was my code:

```
#Do the regressions and get residuals for all variables

variables <- as.matrix( mydata[,x:y] )
allfits<-lm(variables~Drug*Pollutant,data=mydata)
allresiduals<-residuals(allfits)

#Shapiro test on all of it
residuals<-as.data.frame(allresiduals)
lshap <- lapply(residuals, shapiro.test)
lres <- sapply(lshap, `[`, c("p.value"))
lres
```

Please help!  It's driving me crazy.

I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
fligners<-fligner.test(variables~interaction(Pollutant,Drug),data=mydata)
```

I get this error: Error in fligner.test.default(c(1.06, 0.98, 0.94, 0.95, 1.08, 0.95, 0.76,  : 
  'x' and 'g' must have the same length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example

```
data(CO2)
mydata <- CO2

# columns to apply fligner test to
cols <- 4:5

# interaction columns
factor_cols <- 2:3

# apply test
fligner <- sapply(cols, function(x) {
    fligner.test(mydata[,x] ~ 
                 interaction(mydata[,factor_cols[1]], mydata[,factor_cols[2]]))
})

# get p-values
p.values <- apply(fligner, 2, function(x) {
    x$p.value
})

# p.values = 1.0000000 0.2983002
```

Of course my data set isn't well-suited to this hypothesis test. However, the p-value for the first test was 1 and the p-value for the second test was 0.2983.

Answer (score 0):

A little old-school :) but this works:

```
# Generate some data
testData <- data.frame(factor1 = sample(LETTERS[1:6], 100, T),
  factor2 = sample(LETTERS[7:10], 100, T), 
  var1 = rnorm(100), var2 = rnorm(100), var3 = rnorm(100))

# Create formulae - I've used all columns starting var* as the Dependant Variables
formulae <- paste( grep("^var", names(testData), value = TRUE), " ~ interaction(factor1, factor2)")

# Apply the function
pValues <- sapply(formulae, function(F, DAT) fligner.test(as.formula(F), data = DAT)$p.value, DAT = testData)
pValues
```

May be cleaner to split it like this, on the "be kinder to future you" philosophy ...

```
# Funtion that performs a fligner test and returns a P value
flignerP <- function(V, data) {
  theForm <- as.formula(paste(V, "~ interaction(factor1, factor2)"))
  fligner.test(theForm, data = data)$p.value
}

# Perform the test on the var* variables
theVars <- grep("^var", names(testData), value = TRUE)
sapply(theVars, flignerP, data = testData)
```